# JSF does not call setter method of selected Item

Tags: forms, integer, int, setter, jsf-1.2

Here is a JSF 1.1 form

```
<h:form>
    <h1>STEP 1 - Choose your channels</h1>        
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{globalTVRegistration.selectedChannels}" layout="pageDirection">
            <f:selectItems value="#{globalTVRegistration.availableChannels}" />                
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:commandButton value="Select Channels" action="packages" />
</h:form>
```

and its corresponding backing bean

```
public class GlobalTVRegistration {

    private int[] selectedChannels;

    public int[] getSelectedChannels() {
        return selectedChannels;
    }

    public void setSelectedChannels(int[] selectedItems) {
        this.selectedChannels = selectedItems;
    }

}
```

When I select one or more checkboxes and click the command button, the same page is refreshed again. The form submission does not call **setSelectedChannels(int[] selectedItems)**.

Can you identify the problem?

Comment: JSF 1.1 has several painful bugs. Consider upgrading to latest JSF 1.2. You can get it from http://javaserverfaces.java.net. By the way, doing business logic in getter methods is a bad idea. Move that code to constructor `public GlobalTVRegistration()` and keep the single line `return availableChannels;` in the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others also face the same problem, on line

```
private int[] selectedChannels;
```

replace **int** data type with **Integer**.